# List per Date python

Tags: python, django, loops

I am creating a list page and I have this concept. this is my data

```
        List = [
    {'exec_date': datetime.date(2015, 9, 30), 'name': 'AAA', 'status': 'PE'},
    {'exec_date': datetime.date(2015, 10, 29), 'name': 'BBB', 'status': 'DN'}, 
    {'exec_date': datetime.date(2015, 9, 30), 'name': 'CCC', 'status': 'PE'}, 
    {'exec_date': datetime.date(2015, 9, 30), 'name': 'DDD', 'status': 'DN'}, 
    {'exec_date': datetime.date(2015, 9, 7), 'name': 'EEE', 'status': 'DN'}, 
    {'exec_date': datetime.date(2015, 9, 30), 'name': 'FFF', 'status': 'NY'}]
```

and I would like to display an output like this

```
2015-9-7
    1. EEE, DN
2015-9-30
    1. AAA, PE
    2. CCC, PE
    3. DDD, DN
    4. FFF, NY
2015-10-29
    1. BBB, DN
```

I am thinking about for loop but I would like to display dates only once and not repeat it.

@Gocht This is the result. as I have noticed. Sept. 30, 2015 repeats 3 times.

```
    Sept. 30, 2015
        1.Set Task Finished, PE
    Oct. 29, 2015
        1.New Activity for a Task, DN
    Sept. 30, 2015
        1.New Activity from a User, PE
        2.New Activity from a User, DN
    Sept. 7, 2015
        1.New Activity for a Task, DN    
    Sept. 30, 2015
        1.New Activity from a User, NY
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
from django.db.models import F
Model.objects.values('Date').distinct().annotate(name=F('Name'), status=F('Status'))
```

**EDIT**

One option to show this in template is usgin [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup) template tag, and [forloop](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#for) to show an index number:

```
{% regroup List by exec_date as list_data %}

<ul>
{% for exec_date in list_data %}
    <li>{{ exec_date.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for item in exec_date.list %}
          <li> {{ forloop.counter }}.{{ item.name }}, {{ item.status }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Hi thanks... I updated my question... This is what I really mean. Now I am trying to seach tutorials how to use annotate and distinct as you suggested... thank you

Comment: yes I helps... this is close to what I am imagining. however. this is the result when I ran it. I will update my question so you would see it... Thanks again @Gocht

Comment: I got it!! I just added .orderby('exec_date')

Comment: Yes, I was thinking you need to change yuor query.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to sort your list is with the [sort](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html) function as so:

```
List.sort(key=lambda a: a['exec_date'])
```

After the list is properly sorted, you can then iterate over the list items and display them as needed.